# Inverting particles direction from emitter

Tags: particles

I want to invert the flow direction of emitter particles. Instead of the emission going outwards, I want it go inwards. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under *Velocity > Normal*, choose a negative value:

[image]